# .Net Core HttpClient - Typed Client lifetime

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, httpclient

I am trying to inject `IHttpClientFactory` in my service for external api calls and use with DI Container. Because creating a new `HttpClient` object for per request has critic problems as you can see in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests?mvpaWT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003875) for using a "Typed Client", i need to register my services like this in startup.cs

```
services.AddHttpClient<IMyService, MyService>(options => 
{
   options.BaseUrl = new Uri("https://myApi.com");
   // you can also give default request headers here.
   // And you can use polly for resillience of your services.
});
```

And my service

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
  private HttpClient _client;
  private ILogger<MyService> _logger;
  private IAnotherSingletonService _anotherSingletonService;
   
  public MyService(
    HttpClient client,
    ILogger<MyService> logger,
    IAnotherSingletonService anotherSingletonService)
  {
    _client = client;
    _logger = logger;
    _anotherSingletonService = anotherSingletonService;
  }

  public async Task MyMethod()
  {
    var URL = "/api/products"; //base url is in startup.cs already
    var response = await _client.GetAsync(URL);

    //use other registered services...
  }
}
```

So, my question is `AddHttpClient` adds my service with Transient Lifetime. This is called "Typed Client". But i want to make `MyService` singleton. And i want to know how can i do this by using a Typed Client.

---

**EDIT** - Second Way:

Here i tried a basic usage of `IHttpClientFactory`

in `Startup.cs`

```
services.AddHttpClient();
services.AddSingleton<IMyService, MyService>();
```

MyService

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
  private IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;
  private ILogger<MyService> _logger;
  private IAnotherSingletonService _anotherSingletonService;
   
  public MyService(
    IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory,
    ILogger<MyService> logger,
    IAnotherSingletonService anotherSingletonService)
  {
    _httpClientFactory= httpClientFactory;
    _logger = logger;
    _anotherSingletonService = anotherSingletonService;
  }

  public async Task MyMethod()
  {
    using(var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient())
    {
        var URL = "/api/products"; //base url is in startup.cs already
        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(URL);
    }


    //use other registered services...
  }
}
```

Comment: You should definitely not make your `MyService` a Singleton, because that leads to the problem of failing to handle DNS changes, as discussed in the article you referred to. In my opinion, the only suitable lifestyle for `MyService` is `Scoped`, which I expressed in [this bug report](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/36067) on the `AddHttpClient` method.

Comment: @Steven Hi sir, glad that i found someone who realizes this issue. So i cant use my service as singleton because of dns issues. Because when i do this, i am having only one ihttpclientfactory instance, so thats why dns issues coming in, right? But sir cant i use MyService as singleton? i dont want to my code hit to constructor every time MyService works. Because there is no need this. I only have another singleton service instance and logger instance which is singleton also. Do you suggest me to use basic usage? i edit my question added basic usage. Can you check it? This usage is wrong also?

Comment: " i am having only one ihttpclientfactory instance, so thats why dns issues coming in, right?" No, that's not it. DNS issues come from having only one `HttpClient` instance, which is why the `IHttpClientFactory` exists; to create new `HttpClient` instances. If you want `MyService` to be a Singleton, you should inject the `IHttpClientFactory` into it and create and dispose `HttpClients` in each method. This is what you're doing in your "Secod Way". The only thing you are forgetting is to dispose the `httpClient` at the end of `MyMethod`.

Comment: @Steven disposing like using statement is okay? i edited my code again. Thank you again sir!

Comment: Yes, this is correct. `HttpClient` instances, created by `IHttpClientFactory` should be disposed as soon as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems with the original `HttpClient`:

- Using `using (new HttpClient())` can cause port exhaustion, because it's using a separate connection per `HttpClient` instance.
- Using `static HttpClient` can miss DNS updates, because it's using a single connection indefinitely.

TL;DR: Since .NET Core 2.1, you can use a `static HttpClient`. You still shouldn't use `using (new HttpClient())`.

[Longer answer](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/httpclient-connection-pooling-in-dotnet-core):

The problem isn't actually about `HttpClient` instances; it's about the socket lifetime, which is controlled by the inner `HttpMessageHandler` (or the last `HttpMessageHandler` if you have delegating handlers).

In .NET Core 2.0 and earlier, this was [`HttpClientHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058) by default. `HttpClientHandler` makes one socket connection per instance. So, to work around this problem, the ASP.NET team created `IHttpClientFactory`, which pools the `HttpClientHandler`s (not the `HttpClient` wrappers, which are created and destroyed as needed).

In .NET Core 2.1 and newer, the default inner handler is [`SocketsHttpHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.socketshttphandler?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058), which has its *own* pool of connections. So, on these platforms, a single `static HttpClient` instance is fine. You *may* wish to set the `PooledConnectionLifetime` property if you want to proactively detect DNS changes.

Some people still *prefer* `IHttpClientFactory` because of its fluent DI syntax, but it's no longer *required*.

And in your case, since your service is a singleton, you can't use the typed clients (which is the nicest DI syntax IMO). So you have two options:

1. Use `IHttpClientFactory` and get an `HttpClient` as necessary (as in your edit). In this case, the factory will pool `HttpClientHandler`s for the `HttpClient` instances (and each `HttpClientHandler` is a connection).
2. Use a `static HttpClient`. In this case, the `SocketsHttpHandler` created by the `HttpClient` will pool its own connections.

There are some advantages to `IHttpClientFactory` (e.g., you could use a named client and still get the nice DI syntax); and there are some advantages to `SocketsHttpHandler` (e.g., [performance and cross-platform consistency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058#net-core)). In the end, the decision is up to you; there isn't one clear winner.

Comment: Thank you sir, you made my head clear. Actually i was plannig to use a "Typed Client" and make my service singleton(because of its nice DI syntax). But as you said, i can't use a typed client with a singleton service. So for me second choice using `IHttpClientFactory` and pool the Handlers for instances. Beside of this register my service as singleton. And most importantly disposing httpClient (which factory CreateClient method gives us) after using it.